# How to use get_the_post_thumbnail(); for a secondary featured image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails

I have two featured images on my wordpress custom post type products.

[image: featured and secondary image]

I registerd the secondary image with this code:

```
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
 new MultiPostThumbnails(
    array(
        'label' => 'Secondary Image',
        'id' => 'secondary-image',
        'post_type' => 'product'
    )
 );
}
```

Now I wish to call the secondary image. The Product image is successfully called with this funciton   `echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $_product->id);`

However, I cannot manipulate that wordpress function to fetch the custom Secondary Image instead. I have also tried `the_post_thumbnail();` without success, and haven't found another way to grab this.

Edit:

For clarity I want to echo the secondary image on a different page. I tried using the product ID with `$_product->id` to isolate the specific post this image is related too, however,  all the available wordpress functions only fetch the Product image, and I cannot for the life of me get the other images :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the [FAQ](https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-do-i-use-a-custom-thumbnail-size-in-my-theme)

Register a new thumbnail size (optional)

```
add_image_size('post-secondary-image-thumbnail', 250, 150);
```

And then in your theme:

```
MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image', NULL,  'post-secondary-image-thumbnail');
```

**EDIT**
In light of the modified question, to call the image outside of the loop, and thus specific an ID yourself you need to use the [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki/Functions-and-Template-Tags#get_the_post_thumbnail) method.

```
MultiPostThumbnails::get_the_post_thumbnail(
    'product,
    'secondary-image',
    $product->id,
    'post-secondary-image-thumbnail',
    null
)
```

Comment: Yes, I understand this portion. sorry, I might not have been specific enough. I want to use the product ID with the command `$_product->id` to post the images on a page that is seperate from the post.

Comment: Please try to be more specific in the future. Better questions get better answers. See my edit... and read through the Multi Post Thumbnail docs, they are pretty thorough.

Comment: Thank you, this little fix is streamlining a process that would otherwise amount to hundreds of hours of extra photoshop work down the road :)

One thing, there were two minor typos that should be fixed for future viewers of this. `'product,` is missing a quote, and also, `$product->id` should be `$_product->id`.